# Overridable Flows - Does making edits to it and saving it always require a net new flow to be created?

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package

I would like to learn a bit more about Overridable flows.

Based on Salesforce documentation, it seems like as a package developer you can mark Flows as overridable as a means for admins to make edits to them. However, when testing this, it is requiring me to save the flow as "save as" causing it to create a net new flow (that is no longer in the managed state) vs a new version of the flow that was deployed from the package.

Below is the message I get when saving.

```
This creates a flow that overrides and is linked to the original flow. Then any requests execute the override, and not the original flow. Use an override to customize parts of an application in a managed package.
```

Is there a way that I can make edits to the flow that was deployed from the package and just save it as a new version so it retains it's managed state.

What does it mean when it says *Use an override to customize parts of an application in a managed package.*

[image]

Documentation
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_overrides.htm&release=234&type=5